# How can I BLE broadcast in NativeScript?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript

I would like to ask, how is it possible to act as a Bluetooth low energy broadcaster in NativeScript?

I can't really find any examples or libraries related to this. 
Every resources I found seems to be about central devices.
I don't want to connect or anything complicated, just simply advertise something.

How can I achieve this in NativeScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today I don't think there is any plugin that supports advertising over BLE. You may want to write one or directly use the advertisement apis for [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/turning_an_ios_device_into_an_ibeacon?language=objc) / [Android](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising).

Learn more about accessing native apis for [iOS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) / [Android](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) from the {N} docs.